# How do two different string instances with same value stored in the Heap?

Tags: c#, string

For below:

```
string A = "A";
string A1 = "A";
string B = "AB".Substring(0,1);

Console.WriteLine("{0}", object.ReferenceEquals(A, A1));  //Returns True

Console.WriteLine("{0}", object.ReferenceEquals(A, B));  //Returns Flase
```

`object.ReferenceEquals(A, A1)` returns true because they are the two same instance, can I understand that these two reference to the same value in the Heap, which is `A`? If I am wrong, how could the result be explained by `String is immutable`?

For `object.ReferenceEquals(A, B)` returns false, is `"AB".Substring(0,1)` stored in the Heap separately from `A`?

Comment: Yes, `A` and `A1` are both references to the same object, whereas the result of your `Substring` operation is a reference to a separate object.

Comment: `A` and `A1` are references to the same object, because of [string interning](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/09/28/string-interning-and-string-empty/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string A = "A";
string A1 = "A";
```

In the above case, the compiler sets both `A` and `A1` to the same string literal value in the executable image.

```
string B = "AB".Substring(0,1);
```

Internally `Substring` allocates a new string, it does not perform the "substring slice" optimization that other languages/platforms do even though C# strings are immutable, this is because the .NET `String` class's internal value representation does not share string array pointers with other instances.

You can make `A` and `B` the same by using `String.Intern`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

`A` and `A1` variables store reference to the same object in heap, because of mechanism known as [String interning](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning). It's an optimization made by compiler, so it works only for literals.
`B` is calculated at runtime thus it won't be put into pool.

It's possible to add value to the pool manually with use of [`String.Intern`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Also it's possible to disable this mechanism for specific assemblies adding [`CompilationRelaxationAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.compilationrelaxationsattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) with `CompilationRelaxations.NoStringInterning` value at assembly level.

This optimization isn't .Net specific, Java for example has similar pool for strings as well as integers from -128 to 127 and some other primitive types.